# How to get image to fit inside card

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to get a design like this using the card widget:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Tn7.png)

However this is the result I get after running my code: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmTSP.png)

Here's my code for it:

```
class ArticleCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ArticleCard({Key key, this.article}) : super(key: key);

  @required
  final Article article;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card( // Card has a custom border on it
      elevation: 0,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Material(
            shape: SquircleBorder(radius: 55), // Custom border
            child: Image.network(
              article.getImageUrl, // Some image url
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: 150,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 12),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              article.title, // Article text
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .headline6
                  .copyWith(color: cantonGrey[900]),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 12),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `Row` widget you must insert `IntrinsicHeight` widget and set `crossAxisAlignment.stretch` for `Row` widget.

Result:
[image]

Code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 700,
            child: Card(
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(
                      "https://html5css.ru/css/img_forest.jpg",
                      width: 150,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                        child: Text(
                          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas placerat, ante fermentum tempus dapibus, diam justo vehicula est, nec gravida lacus tortor vel quam. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque id pharetra nibh, quis eleifend augue. Suspendisse pulvinar a augue ac eleifend. In nec hendrerit justo. Donec mauris ex, porttitor vel tincidunt sed, suscipit vitae quam. Duis interdum leo purus, at sollicitudin ligula blandit in. Vivamus semper magna quis nulla porta, et maximus leo imperdiet. ",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fill the image to its parent, simply wrap your image to the `FittedBox` and set `BoxFit.fill`.

```
FittedBox(
  child: Image.asset('foo.png'),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
)
```

Comment: This did not change problem :(

Answer (score 0):

try also give height in image:

```
class ArticleCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ArticleCard({Key key, this.article}) : super(key: key);

  @required
  final Article article;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card( // Card has a custom border on it
      elevation: 0,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Material(
            shape: SquircleBorder(radius: 55), // Custom border
            child: Image.network(
              article.getImageUrl, // Some image url
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: 150,
              height: 150, // or double.infinity
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 12),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              article.title, // Article text
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .headline6
                  .copyWith(color: cantonGrey[900]),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 12),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```